# Output text is not showing in html

Tags: html

Anything after closing `</body>` tag is not visible.

The output text is not visible in a browser. I have tried adding and removing `<div>` and `<body>` tags around it. I can't seem to troubleshoot my mistake.

```css
h1{
    font-family: 'Inknut Antiqua', sans-serif;
    color: rgb(255, 118, 193);
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    right: 1020px;    
}
.logo{
    float: left;
    width: 5%;
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    left: 40px;
}
#bg{ 
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    justify-content: space-between;
    display: flex;
    background-color: rgb(222, 255, 102);
}
h4{
    color: black;
    font-size: x-large;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Giovanni's Guitars</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inknut+Antiqua:wght@300&display=swap"
        type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>
    <header id="bg">
        <div>
            <h1>Giovanni's Guitars</h1>
            <img class="logo" src="logo1.svg" alt="a logo">

        </div>
    </header>

</body>

<div>
    <h4>Guitars and Bases</h4>
</div>

</html>
```

Please help me.

Comment: The `body` tag wraps the entire content of the page. Anything you want to display needs to be inside of it.

Answer (score 3):

Your div tag should be inside the body tag

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Giovanni's Guitars</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inknut+Antiqua:wght@300&display=swap"
        type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>
    <header id="bg">
        <div>
            <h1>Giovanni's Guitars</h1>
            <img class="logo" src="logo1.svg" alt="a logo">

        </div>
    </header>
<div>
    <h4>Guitars and Bases</h4>
</div>
</body>



</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. HTML is designed in a way that all page elements are placed inside the `<body></body>` element.

If you need a wrapper just add a `<div>` inside your `<body>` element.

Comment: I did just that but the output is still nothing but a blank screen.

Answer (score 0):

All your content should be inside your body element.

In addition, in your #bg selector you set position="fixed" which makes the other content after it to "disappeared".

It is not the best practice, but you can do it like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Giovanni's Guitars</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inknut+Antiqua:wght@300&display=swap"
      type="text/css"
    />
  </head>

  <body>
    <header id="bg">
      <div>
        <img class="logo" src="logo1.svg" alt="a logo" />
        <h1>Giovanni's Guitars</h1>
      </div>
    </header>

    <div class="content">
      <h4>Guitars and Bases</h4>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>

h1 {
  font-family: "Inknut Antiqua", sans-serif;
  color: rgb(255, 118, 193);
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.logo {
  width: 5%;
  margin: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#bg {
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  position: fixed;
  justify-content: space-between;
  display: flex;
  background-color: rgb(222, 255, 102);
}
h4 {
  color: black;
  font-size: x-large;
  text-align: center;
}

.content {
    margin-top: 150px;
}
```

Comment: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AjzpH-tDXPDAhUCRpo6D8v1iNs77?e=Zcezd8 i want to start witing below from it and conserve the position="fixed" property. is there any work around it?

Comment: See my comment above

Answer (score 0):

Your body tag should be closed before html tag.